# Solve $\int_0^1\frac{x^7-1}{\ln x}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

This integral is driving me nuts for quite some time:

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^7-1}{\ln x}dx$$

Mathematica spits out the result in a second ($\ln 8)$. My attempts revolved around substitution: if you introduce $u=\ln x$ you get something like:

$$\int_{-\infty}^0\frac{(e^{7u}-1)e^u}{u}du$$

...which looks equally hopeless as the starting integral. The other attempt was to try some kind of recurrence relation between $I_n(x)$ defined as:

$$I_n(x)=\int\frac{x^n}{\ln x}dx$$

...or to find a recurrence relation between $I_n$ defined as:

$$I_n=\int_0^1\frac{x^n-1}{\ln x}dx$$,

but the things have spiraled out of controll pretty fast. Also attempts to use Taylor explansion proved to be a dead end. Any hints?

Comment: Feynman’s trick? Set the power of $x$ to $a$.

Comment: Search for Feynman's technique. This has already been asked multiple times on this website.

Comment: @zwim Perfect, thanks!

Comment: @Tavish So simpe, yet unknown to me.

Comment: @Oldboy Not anymore!

Comment: @Tavish Thanks again!